# how to include/call profile2 registration form in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I have created a another profile student, and added a field called class. i want to display this form including the class filed.

How to display the student registration form .. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used below code in block

```
<?php
     print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));
$profile = profile2_load_by_user($account);
print drupal_render(field_view_field('profile2', $profile['Student'], 'field_class'));
?>
```